# How can i make values tuples?

Tags: python

```
d1 = {1 : 2, 3 : 4, 5 : 4, 7 : 2, 9 : 4}
def swap_dict (d):
    rd = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        rd[v] = rd.get(v, []) + [k]
    return rd
print(swap_dict(d1))
```

Values shlould be tuples - how to do it?

Show `{2: [1, 7], 4: [3, 5, 9]}`

Must `{2: (1, 7), 4: (3, 9, 5)}`

Comment: Do `rd = {k: tuple(v) for k, v in rd.items()}` before `return`

Comment: show - can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple

Comment: It works fine for me. You should add that line **after** for loop and **before** return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It worked for me

```
d1 = {1 : 2, 3 : 4, 5 : 4, 7 : 2, 9 : 4}
def swap_dict (d):
    rd = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        rd[v] = rd.get(v, []) + [k]
    return rd
d2 = swap_dict(d1)
print({key: tuple(value) for key, value in d2.items()})
```